# I'm making a function that return the sum of the all number in the FizzBuzz list. I thought it would be fine but not working. In Python

Tags: python

The result is 0
It should be 60 if I type 15 but not. I don't know why but n_numlist is empty. Where is my mistake?
I cannot find it!! Is there someone who can find? Please help me!!

```
#This is my code:

def to_fizzbuzz(number):
    if number % 15 == 0:
        return 'FizzBuzz'

    if number % 3 == 0:
        return 'Fizz'

    if number % 5 == 0:
        return 'Buzz'

    else:
        return str(number)
        # return i

def main():
    N = int(input())
    # this list concludes "FizzBuzz", "Fizz" or "Buzz"
    fblist = []
    for number in range(1, 10**6):
        result = to_fizzbuzz(number)
        fblist.append(result)

    # the list up to N
    n_list = fblist[0:N]
    # this list contains only numbers and up to N

    n_numlist = []

    for s in n_list:
        if s.isdigit == True:
            n_numlist.append(s)

    print(sum(n_numlist))


main()
```

Comment: did you try to print the first elements of fblist and n_list to see if it corresponds to your expectations?

Comment: 1) `isdigit` is a function. You probably mean to say `if s.isidigt()` (unrelatedly, the `== True` does nothing).

2) What do you expect a sum of a list of strings (`n_numlist`) to give you?

Comment: > glagla: I tried for n_list and It was successful but for fblist and n_numlist not fblist is like the repetition from 1 to 15 and fblist is empty

Comment: >gspr: 1) okay so that mean that I cannot use isdigit here? cus it's a function? 2) If input is 15, 60

Comment: > glagla and gspr: Thank you for replying ! It so helpful

Comment: > All: Thank you all ! Now I figured it out. Now I learned something from all of you guys that make me smarter!  I appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your `for s in n_list` loop to this:

```py
for s in n_list:
    if s.isdigit() == True:
        n_numlist.append(int(s))
```

Because `isdigit()` is a function, you need to add `()` to the end of it to call it.

Because you return your numbers as strings - `return str(number)` -
it can't sum them, so you need to convert them back to integers when you append them to `n_numlist`.

Comment: > David Sanders: Thank you for replying ! I edited as you said and now it works! I tend to forget to add () I learned. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

```
x = int(input())

inputList = list(range(1,x+1)) #creating a list [1,x]
stringList = [str(a) for a in inputList] #changing int elements to string

for n, i in enumerate(stringList): #n shows which element from list, i shows this element

    if int(i) %15 == 0: #changing to int because we are doing math
        stringList[n] = "FizzBuzz" 

    elif int(i) %5 == 0:
        stringList[n] = "Fizz"

    elif int(i) %3 == 0:
        stringList[n] = "Buzz"

print(stringList) #let's see our new list

last_list = [] #lets add output list

for a in stringList: 
        if a.isdigit() == True: #you forgot put () to isdigit by the way 
            last_list.append(a) 

int_last_list = [int(a) for a in last_list] #we are changing all elements to int because we are going to do some math.

print(sum(int_last_list))
```

Comment: well it seems you've complated your problem, sorry I am beginner and I tried to make BuzzFeed thing by myself. Thanks for experience tho^^